# Why are these two snippets of code not giving same output?

Tags: java, c++, bit-manipulation

I am trying to reverse bits of a number. C++ code is working fine but java is giving wrong output

c++:

```
class Solution {
public:uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
uint32_t ans=0,k=32;
while(k--)ans=ans*2+n%2,n/=2;
return ans;
}
};
```

Java:

```
 public int reverseBits(int n) {
        int out=0;
       int k=32;
        while(k--!=0){
            out=out*2+n%2;
            n/=2;
        }
        return out;


    }
```

Input
11111111111111111111111111111101

Output
  1073741824 (01000000000000000000000000000000)

Expected
  3221225471 (10111111111111111111111111111111)

Comment: Whats input and whats outcome you need?

Comment: You have to check both variable in while condition `while (k-- > 0 && n > 0)`.

Comment: To begin with: In C++ you use `uint32_t` (an _unsigned_ int), while in Java you use _signed_ int.

Comment: i have added  input that is causing error in java,in c++ all inputs working fine

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have unsigned integers on contrary of C++. So, I think you can pass `long` to your function, and traverse only the first 32 bits. What, I think, should me modified is only the prototype to have the argument to be `long`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Java 8 does have functions to deal with unsigned integers, although it's still not convenient

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'uint32_t' - use int in c++ as you are using int in java. 
**int - signed int.** (Covers both negative and positive integers). 
**uint32_t - unsigned int** (Covers only positive integers so twice limit than signed int).


**Used bit to differentiate both negative & positive numbers in signed int is left most bit so reversing bit results different results in both.** 


You can read about unsigned int vs signed int (which is default) to understand exact representations.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
uint32_t ans=0,k=32;
while(k--)ans=ans*2+n%2,n/=2;
return ans;
}

int reverseBitsInt(int n) {
int ans=0,k=32;
while(k--)ans=ans*2+n%2,n/=2;
return ans;
}
};

int main()
{
    Solution s{};
    cout << s.reverseBits(1) << "   (Unsigned Int)" << endl;
    cout << s.reverseBitsInt(1) << "  (Java - SignedInt)" << endl;
}
```

**Output:**
2147483648   (Unsigned Int)
-2147483648  (Java - SignedInt)


Hope this answers your question.